# Need Help Project Euler Problem 7: Finding the 10001st Prime Number

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing Project Euler on freecodecamp and I'm currently working on problem 7. My answer seems to be stuck at the last test case, the 10001st prime number. The terminal is giving me an error. However, I have passed the prime number tests before. Here is my code:

```
function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true
}


function nthPrime(n) {

  let arr = [];
  let count = 2;
  while (arr.length < n) {
    if(isPrime(count)){
      arr.push(count)
    }
    count++;
  }
  return arr[n-1];
}



nthPrime(10001);
```

and terminal:

// running tests
nthPrime(10001) should return 104743.

// tests completed

// console output

Potential infinite loop detected on line 15. Tests may be failing because of this.

Potential infinite loop detected on line 15. Tests may be failing because of this.

Is it possible that you've encountered an issue in a certain part of my code?

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: THIS IS NOT SERIOUS**

Maybe get rid of loops and use recursion instead? (Be patient, it takes a bit of time before completed)

```js
const isPrime = n => rec(
  (v, done, loop) => 
    n <= v
      ? done(true)
      : n % v === 0 
      ? done(false) 
      : loop(v + 1),
  2
);

const nthPrime = n => rec(
  ([v, p, c], done, loop) => 
    p >= n
      ? done(v)
      : isPrime(c)
        ? loop([c, p + 1, c + 1])
        : loop([v, p, c + 1]),
  [0, 0, 2]
);


/* --- rec helper function for trampolining */
function rec(f, init) {
  let res = rec.Step(init);
  while (res && res instanceof rec.Step) {
    res = f(res.value, rec.Done, rec.Step);
  }
  return res.value;
}
rec.Done = function (v) {
  const r = Object.create(rec.Done.prototype);
  r.value = v;
  return r;
};
rec.Step = function (v) {
  const r = Object.create(rec.Step.prototype);
  r.value = v;
  return r;
}


console.log(nthPrime(10001));
```

**HONESTLY**

I get the impression, that the potentially-infinite-loop-detection mechanism isn't working properly/freecodecamp has a *bug* and you cannot complete the task. *Regardless of what you do*, the message shows and the code does *not* complete the final test `nthPrime(10001)`. This happens with your original code *as well as* my recursive solution *although* both give the correct result of `104743` when you test them (run the snippets).

```js
function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true
}


function nthPrime(n) {
  let arr = [];
  let count = 2;
  while (arr.length < n) {
    if(isPrime(count)){
      arr.push(count)
    }
    count++;
  }
  return arr[n-1];
}

console.log(nthPrime(10001));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and assistance. I thought there was an issue with my code, and I didn't run the code locally for testing. It made me believe there was a problem on my end.

Thank you again for your help.